# How to get windows to "fit" to corners/edges of screen on a Mac when dragging

Tags: linux, macos, desktop, window

I use both Linux (Xubuntu) and Mac (Yosemite) regularly. One of the features that I love in Xubuntu that I have been as yet unable to replicate on my Mac is the tendency of Xubunu to "grab" windows when I'm dragging them on screen near an edge/corner and fit them snugly to the edges. When I move windows to the edges on the Mac, I have to do it by hand, and often miss a tiny bit of "wasted" screen space, or a small piece of the window that ends up offscreen because I didn't drop in the perfect spot. I've been unable to replicate this functionality using Better Touch Tool (though I could be simply getting it wrong) or anything else. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I use [window tidy](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/window-tidy/id456609775?mt=12) for positioning windows.

There seems to be [Spectacle](http://spectacleapp.com/) that free, but I haven't tried it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

I use [BetterSnapTool](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12).  Well worth the $2.  It just works!